# Calculate the rotation in degrees of a rectangle on its axis to form a cylinder of said rectangles

Tags: circles, ratio

Im working with rectangles in 3D space that rotate by degrees around an origin of its parent object.

I want to calculate how to make a perfect Cylinder / Circle from `r` radius. Essentially I want to be able to generate the correct rectangle width, count and degree of rotation for a circle with a specific radius / diameter.

For example, I can create a circle for this 3D shape out of rectangular pieces with each piece being of the rotation `22.5` degrees.

[image]

Each "rectangle" is a voxel, so each must conform to being a whole number in width and height

such as `1 x 2` or `4 x 8`

Is there a simple way to calculate the perfect width I would need each rectangle to be, and how many degrees to rotate each one with a formula?

The only thing I want to be able to define is the circle's radius. Nothing else, as that should be procedurally created by my input radius.

The issue is, I don't have a lot of experience in math, so I have no idea how to do what I want.

**To Clarify: Each rectangle inherits the transform of the one behind it. So if I rotate the first rectangle `22.5` degrees, all children will be rotated `22.5` degrees plus their own transforms.**

*PS, incase someone needs to create a formula reversed / based off of my example given:
The radius of the circle in the image is 5 voxels / 5 units, and it's diameter is 10 voxels.
Each piece of the circle is rotated 22.5 degrees exactly. Each of those rectangles are 2 units / voxels wide.*

To simplify everything above: I essentially need to be able to generate the exact voxel width / count and degree of rotation for each one based off of one number: The circle's radius / diameter... Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, in order to get a 16 sided polygon ( not a circle) you need 16 trapeziums  of vertex angle $22.5^{\circ}$( not rectangles)
arranged end to end.

Vertex angle 2π/n is required for n vertices/corners.

Comment: Essentially, yes. I just want to know if there is a formula that can generate a polygon of a set radius and width a number of sides / degree of rotations based on the length of the sides..

So for example, I could input a radius of 6, and have widths of the rectangles and their degree of rotation pre-determined, so I could automate the process of making low resolution circles.

Comment: I guess vertex angle $ 2 \pi/n \text{ for }n $ vertices/corners.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but could you put that in your answer? Id appreciate it

Comment: Thanks, by using your suggestion I figured it out. First use 2π/n like you said to get the radian angle from the number of corners. Then you convert that to Degrees using x 180/π. However, this removes the use of the first two formulas... You could literally use 360/n to get the rotation in degrees from n sides.